# Private GIT repository under HTTP/APACHE

Tags: git, apache, http

I just want to make a private reposity over http using apache. But I can't force to the server to ask for user/password when I do the git PULL. Only ask for user/pass when I PUSH.

The reposity is in **c:/htdocs/git/test.git**

My **httpd.conf:**

```
<Directory />
    #AllowOverride none
    #Require all denied
</Directory>

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT G:/htdocs/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER 

ScriptAlias /git/ "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/"

<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI 
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAliasMatch \
        "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
                    info/refs | \
                    objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                             [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                             pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                    git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"

<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git"
    AuthUserFile "G:/gitSecurity/password.git"
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

What I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having just solved this, I think the problem is that your `LocationMatch` only checks when someone is pushing (`git-receive-pack`).  You need to use a `Location` directive that applies to all access to git repos, as in

```
<Location "/git">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Access"
    AuthUserFile "/var/lib/apache2/passwd/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```